# php ajax droplist problems

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu, dreamweaver

i am creating 2 drop down list that the second one is based on the selection of the first drop down list. the data are retrieved from the mysql database

## country.sql

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Mar 01, 2013 at 12:44 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.24-log
-- PHP Version: 5.4.3

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `lam_el_chamel_db`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `country`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `country` (
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `country`
--

INSERT INTO `country` (`country_id`, `country_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Lebanon'),
(2, 'Afghanistan'),
(3, 'Albania'),
(4, 'Algeria'),
(5, 'Andorra'),
(6, 'Angola'),
(7, 'Antigua and Barbuda'),
(8, 'Argentina'),
(9, 'Armenia'),
(10, 'Australia'),
(11, 'Austria'),
(12, 'Azerbaijan'),
(13, 'Bahamas'),
(14, 'Bahrain'),
(15, 'Bangladesh'),
(16, 'Barbados'),
(17, 'Belarus'),
(18, 'Belgium'),
(19, 'Belize'),
(20, 'Benin '),
(21, 'Bhutan'),
(22, 'Bolivia'),
(23, 'Bosnia and Herzegovina'),
(24, 'Botswana'),
(25, 'Brazil'),
(26, 'Brunei '),
(27, 'Bulgaria'),
(28, 'Burkina Faso'),
(29, 'Burma'),
(30, 'Burundi'),
(31, 'Cambodia'),
(32, 'Cameroon'),
(33, 'Canada'),
(34, 'Cape Verde'),
(35, 'Central African Republic'),
(36, 'Chad'),
(37, 'Chile'),
(38, 'China'),
(39, 'Colombia'),
(40, 'Comoros '),
(41, 'Congo'),
(42, 'Costa Rica'),
(43, 'Cote d''Ivoire'),
(44, 'Croatia'),
(45, 'Cuba'),
(46, 'Cyprus'),
(47, 'Czech Republic'),
(48, 'Denmark'),
(49, 'Djibouti'),
(50, 'Dominica'),
(51, 'Ecuador'),
(52, 'Egypt'),
(53, 'Estonia'),
(54, 'Ethiopia'),
(55, 'Fiji'),
(56, 'Finland'),
(57, 'France'),
(58, 'Georgia'),
(59, 'Germany'),
(60, 'Ghana'),
(61, 'Greece'),
(62, 'Guatemala'),
(63, 'Guinea'),
(64, 'Haiti'),
(65, 'Hong Kong'),
(66, 'Hungary'),
(67, 'Iceland'),
(68, 'India'),
(69, 'Indonesia'),
(70, 'Iran'),
(71, 'Iraq'),
(72, 'Ireland'),
(73, 'Italy'),
(74, 'Jamaica'),
(75, 'Japan'),
(76, 'Jordan '),
(77, 'Kazakhstan'),
(78, 'Korea, North'),
(79, 'Korea, South'),
(80, 'Kosovo'),
(81, 'Kuwait'),
(82, 'Laos'),
(83, 'Latvia'),
(84, 'Libya'),
(85, 'Luxembourg'),
(86, 'Madagascar'),
(87, 'Malaysia'),
(88, 'Maldives'),
(89, 'Mali'),
(90, 'Malta'),
(91, 'Mauritania'),
(92, 'Mexico'),
(93, 'Moldova'),
(94, 'Monaco'),
(95, 'Montenegro'),
(96, 'Morocco'),
(97, 'Mozambique'),
(98, 'Nepal'),
(99, 'Netherlands'),
(100, 'New Zealand'),
(101, 'Nicaragua'),
(102, 'Nigeria'),
(103, 'Norway'),
(104, 'Oman'),
(105, 'Pakistan'),
(106, 'Palestinian'),
(107, 'Panama'),
(108, 'Paraguay'),
(109, 'Peru'),
(110, 'Philippines'),
(111, 'Poland'),
(112, 'Portugal'),
(113, 'Qatar'),
(114, 'Romania'),
(115, 'Russia'),
(116, 'Saudi Arabia'),
(117, 'Senegal'),
(118, 'Serbia'),
(119, 'Singapore'),
(120, 'Slovakia'),
(121, 'Slovenia'),
(122, 'Spain '),
(123, 'Sri Lanka'),
(124, 'Sudan'),
(125, 'Swaziland '),
(126, 'Sweden'),
(127, 'Syria'),
(128, 'Taiwan'),
(129, 'Tanzania'),
(130, 'Thailand '),
(131, 'Tunisia'),
(132, 'Turkey'),
(133, 'Ukraine'),
(134, 'United Arab Emirates'),
(135, 'United Kingdom'),
(136, 'Uruguay'),
(137, 'Uzbekistan'),
(138, 'Venezuela'),
(139, 'Vietnam'),
(140, 'Yemen'),
(141, 'Zambia'),
(142, 'Zimbabwe ');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

## governorate.sql

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Mar 01, 2013 at 12:45 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.24-log
-- PHP Version: 5.4.3

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `lam_el_chamel_db`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `governorate`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `governorate` (
  `governorate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `governorate_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`governorate_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `governorate`
--

INSERT INTO `governorate` (`governorate_id`, `governorate_name`, `country_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Beirut', 1),
(2, 'Mount Lebanon', 1),
(3, 'North', 1),
(4, 'Beqaa ', 1),
(5, 'Nabatiye', 1),
(6, 'South', 1);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

## index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Playing With Select list</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><style>.main{display:none;} .support-note .note-ie{display:block;}</style><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $(".country").change(function()
        {
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;

        $.ajax
        ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_category.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
        $(".governorate").html(html);
        } 
        });

        });
        });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                <h1><strong>Playing With Select List</strong></h1>
                <h2>Select One List To see Output On Other</h2>
            </header>
        </div>
    <span style="margin-left:22%">
            <label>country :</label> <select name="country" class="category">
<option selected="selected">--Select Country--</option>
<?php
include('db.php');
$sql=mysql_query("select country_id,country_name from country");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id=$row['country_id'];
$data=$row['country_name'];
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
 } ?>
</select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div class="governorate">

<label>Governorate :</label> <select name="governorate" class="subcategory">
<option selected="selected">--Select governorate--</option>

</select>
</div>
</span>
<br><br><br>
                <h1><center><strong>Go To-:<a href="www.tricktodesign.com">TrickToDesign</a></strong></center></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

## ajax_category.php

```
   <?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST['governorate_id'])
{
$id=$_POST['governorate_id'];
$sql=mysql_query("select b.governorate_id,b.governorate_name from governorate a,contry_id b where b.country_id=a.country_id and parent='$id'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
//$id=$row['governorate_id'];
//$data=$row['governorate_name'];

echo"<select name='governorate'>";
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
echo "</select>";
}
}

?>
```

how to make the second drop list appear with data in it that is the error that i face

PS: **i edit the index .php and the ajax_category.php**

Comment: What exactly error do you have?

Comment: it simply do not show the governorate data in the second drop list how to make it appear ?? as i said i think the error is in the query can you help me ??

Comment: on success, you are using ``$(".governorate").html(html);`` where is governate class in index page?

Comment: @devleb i checked it, its hole lot of messy.. i didn't understood what you have done, so i created it for you,, check my answer down..

Answer (score 4):

Your code :

```
success: function(html)
        {
        $(".governorate").html(html);
        }
```

But you don't have `governorate` class in your html

Change your code something like this : (note the wrapped div)

```
<div class="governorate">
<select name="governorate" class="subcategory">
<option selected="selected">--Select governorate--</option>

</select>
<div>
```

In php page :

```
echo "<select name=....>";
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: sir where do i need to create governorate class ??

Comment: wrap your `select` with `div` `<div class="governorate">`, see the answer

Comment: still not getting the data to appear what is the dam error this make me crazy.

Comment: mmmmm i do not know how to use firebug so how can i resolve this error it is very important to finish it

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing your dropdown `(".governorate")` in Jquery. But you don't have any class in your dropdown. Just add a class in that. Change the code to,

```
 $("select[name='governorate']").html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Playing With Select list</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><style>.main{display:none;} .support-note .note-ie{display:block;}</style><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $(".country").change(function()
        {
          var id = $(this).val();

        $.getJSON('new_category.php?id='+id+'', function(data) {
            $('.governorate').html("");
            $('.governorate').append('<option value=0>--Select governorate--</option>');
            $(data).each(function(){
                $('.governorate').append('<option value='+this.governorate_id+'>'+this.governorate_name+'</option>');
                });
            });


            });
        });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                <h1><strong>Playing With Select List</strong></h1>
                <h2>Select One List To see Output On Other</h2>
            </header>
        </div>
    <span style="margin-left:22%">
            <label>country :</label> <select class="country" >
<option selected="selected">--Select Country--</option>
<?php
include('connect.php');
$sql=mysql_query("select country_id,country_name from test1.country");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id=$row['country_id'];
$data=$row['country_name'];
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
 } ?>
</select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label>Governorate :</label> <select class="governorate" >
<option selected="selected">--Select governorate--</option>

</select>
</span>
<br><br><br>
                <h1><center><strong>Go To-:<a href="www.tricktodesign.com">TrickToDesign</a></strong></center></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**new_category.php**

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT governorate_id, governorate_name FROM test1.governorate WHERE country_id=$id");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $gArray['governorate_id'] =  $row['governorate_id'];
    $gArray['governorate_name'] = $row['governorate_name'];
    $g[] = $gArray;
}
echo json_encode($g);


?>
```

brief explanation:

Sending the selected country id, in the get parameter, getJson method will retrieve a json list, which contains governorate details according to id. then each function in jquery will append your details..

Comment: it only work for id 1, that is lebanon, because only that you have inserted in table.

Comment: @ Raghuveer now the 2 drop down list do not work and no data appear

Comment: @devleb what you have done?  can you post your code after modification?